# Algebraically solving the regression equation for a independent variable in python

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I fit a regression model using python `statsmodels.formula.api` package and obtain the coefficients/results. Here's the model:

```
Price ~ Availability + Income + unemployment + labor_force + HH
```

The coefficients are:

```
coef    
Intercept   18.8172
Availability 0.0860 
Income  9.213e-05   
unemployment -1.562e-05 
labor_force 5.78e-06
```

I'd like to calculate the value of Availability for when `Price = 0` and for different values of independent variable which vary by time. Basically, solve for `Availability` when `Price = 0`.

```
0 = Intercept + b1 * Avail + b2 * Income + b3 * U + b4 * L
```

I need python to solve this equation for Avail.

I realize I can do this with a python function or simply solving the equation, however, are there any in built methods I could use to obtain the equation and solve.

Comment: are you looking for https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.from_formula.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.from_formula or this can easily solve using dot product

Comment: statsmodels doesn't have a function for this, but this is easy to implement using numpy